# DropDownList SelectedIndexChanged not getting fired

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ASP.Net: DropDownList's SelectedIndexChanged event not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905406/asp-net-dropdownlists-selectedindexchanged-event-not-firing)

I created a new ASP.NET default website from Visual Studio. I have used a drop down list control on my .aspx page and set the data source for it, which is working fine.

However, I need to use the `SelectedIndex_Changed` event for this `DDlist`, which is not getting fired due to unknown reasons. I have tried putting breakpoints inside the event, but it doesn't even fall inside the function.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Did you set it's AutoPostBack property to true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting `AutoPostBack` to `True`

Answer (score 1):

Just check that have you put **AutoPostBack="true"** in dropdown!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you haven't changed the `AutoPostBack` property to `False`, make sure that your databound ListItems have unique values. Also, the event is `SelectedIndexChanged`, not `SelectedIndex_Changed`,